# asp.net 4.0 Web Forms - validation doesn't work with routing

Tags: validation, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

I have a problem with validation controls in ASP.NET (RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressionValidator) since I've started url routing.

The validation doesn't work both at client side (doesn't show alterts) and server side (allows the unproper data). The code I've used to route url:

```
  routes.MapPageRoute("postName", "{postURL}", "~/Post.aspx");
```

But the thing is, when I changed the route definition to:

```
  routes.MapPageRoute("postName", "post/{postURL}", "~/Post.aspx");
```

validation started to work absolutely correct. But I wish to use the first route definition. Does anyone knows what to do in this situation?

Thanks in advance.